# Bessel function for complex argument in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, arguments, infinite, complex-numbers, bessel-functions

I'm trying to use MATLAB [Bessel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/besselj.html) function of zeroth order ---> `besselj(0,Z)`. What I noticed is: it can handle real part of nth power (say `e100`) but not imaginary part if it is greater than (`e2`) in a complex argument.

Eg: `(2+2*i)` complex argument it will handle. But it can't handle `(20000+20000*i)----->` gives answer as "infinity".

this is what i get :

```
besselj(0,2e4+i*2e4)

ans =

   Inf
```

Can some one explain this? Is there any limit of the power in the imaginary part?

Answer (score 1):

From [Bessel function page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), middle of the page, there is a formula for asymptotic expansion for large complex number with known imaginary part. This expansion has a term of the form `exp(abs(imag(z)))*O(1/abs(z))`, (`O` is the O-notation), so it grows very rapidly with the imaginary part of the input number.

Comment: Thanks Bentoy for replying. So, this means there should be a limit. My program/values are in the range (e3) So, whatever I try it is giving infinity value. How can I proceed then? Is there any other method to overcome this?